# Why is GCC saying multiple definitions of main? I have one main

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I can successfully run and compile my code using microsoft visual studio. When I try to compile it using gcc to submit my program through SSH, I get an error saying multiple definitions of main. I only have one main function, and I don't call my main anywhere.

Here is the compiler's error message:

```
/tmp/ccsoZK9a.o: In function `main':
ipc_ms1_prof.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/cciG56p6.o:ipc_ms1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Prototype Functions
void welcome(void);
void prnTitle();
void prnFooter(double gTotal);
void clrKyb(void);
void pause(void);
int getInt(void);
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);
double getDbl(void);
double getDblLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);

int main(void)
{
int iVal = 0;
double dVal = 0.00;
welcome();
printf("listing header and footer with grand total:\n");
prnTitle();

prnFooter(1234.5678);
printf("listing header and footer without grand total:\n");
prnTitle();
prnFooter(-1);

pause();

printf("Enter an integer: ");
iVal = getInt();
printf("You entered: %d\n", iVal);

printf("Enter an integer between 10 an 20: ");
iVal = getIntLimited(10, 20);
printf("Your entered %d\n", iVal);

printf("Enter a floating point number: ");
dVal = getDbl();
printf("You entered: %0.2lf\n", dVal);

printf("Enter a floating point number between 10.00 and 20.00: ");
dVal = getDblLimited(10.0, 20.0);
printf("You entered: %0.2lf\n", dVal);

printf("End of tester program for milestone one!\n");

return 0;
}

void welcome(void)
{
printf("---=== Grocery Inventory System ===---\n\n");
}
void prnTitle()
{
printf("Row |SKU| Name               | Price  |Taxed| Qty | Min |   Total            |Atn\n");
printf("----+---+--------------------+--------+-----+-----+-----+------------|---\n");
}
void prnFooter(double gTotal)
{
printf("--------------------------------------------------------+----------------\n");
if (gTotal > 0)
    printf("                                           Grand Total: |     %12.2lf\n", gTotal);
}

void clrKyb(void)
{
char input = ' ';
//Keep getting user input as long as input is not equal to enter('\n')
do
{
    scanf("%c", &input);
} while (input != '\n');
}
void pause(void)
{//Pause the program as until the user presses enter
printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
clrKyb();
}

int getInt(void)
{
char NL = 'x';//NL is x because that is one char whereas a number would be     int                                          
int value;
while (NL != '\n') {
    //loop is broken if not \n so it is routed to another loop to keep loop going until \n
    scanf("%d%c", &value, &NL);
    if (NL != '\n') {
        clrKyb();
        printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");
    }
}

return value;

}
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
int value = 0;

value = getInt();
while (value < lowerLimit || value > upperLimit)
{//while user input is not within the right numerical range
    //Display error message
    printf("Invalid value, %d < value < %d: ", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    value = getInt();//call getInt to get user input again
}

return value;
}

double getDbl(void)//Similar to getInt.. double version
{
char NL = 'x';
double value;
while (NL != '\n') {
    scanf("%lf%c", &value, &NL);
    if (NL != '\n') {
        clrKyb();
        printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");
    }
}

return value;
}
double getDblLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
double value = 0;

value = getDbl();
while (value < lowerLimit || value > upperLimit)
{
    printf("Invalid value, %lf < value < %lf: ", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    value = getDbl();
}

return value;
}//Similar to getIntLimited but the double version
```

Comment: _Here is the compiler's error message: /tmp/ccsoZK9a.o: In function main':
**ipc_ms1_prof.c**:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of main' /tmp/cciG56p6.o: **ipc_ms1.c** :(.text+0x0): first defined here collect2: ld returned 1 exit status_ is it enough?

Comment: You are linking two object files (at least) and both the one you show and `ipc_ms1.c` have a `main` function defined in them.

Comment: You guys were right. Appearantly it combined my proffesors source with mine. His was called: ipc_ms1_prof.c Mine was called: ipc_ms1.c . I just read the my school email, he said he forgot to put on the assignment instructions that we should comment out our main function in our code.

Comment: `we should comment out our main function in our code` - that might defy the purpose or the exercise - I'm inclined to suggest _commenting out your professor_'s variant

Answer (score 3):

Check the linker. Usually that means another object file is being compiled at the same time that also contains a main function. There must only be one main function within all associated files.

Comment: You were right. Appearantly it combined my proffesors source with mine.
His was called: ipc_ms1_prof.c
Mine was called: ipc_ms1.c  .
I just read the my school email, he said he forgot to put on the assignment instructions that we should comment out our main function in our code.